# Excel adds "@" symbol in formula

Tags: c#, excel, dynamic-arrays

I am working in C# and Excel.
I have some to code to add a formula to Excel cells:

```cs
excelworksheet_default.Range["K66"].Value = "=MIN(IF((C60:C74)=C64,I60:I74))";
```

My problem is that Excel automatically adds "@" in my formula:

[image: (see image)]

This "@" changed the dynamic array of my formula. [(Here s the link of Microsoft support)](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-functions-that-return-ranges-or-arrays-7d1970e2-cbaa-4279-b59c-b9dd3900fc69?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us).

Do you have any solution to avoid this problem. Thank you for your help. I hoped I well expressed my question.

Comment: Could it be C# is adding that? I have pasted formulae using vba and that has never happened, well at least to me.

Comment: I have closed the question since I think the issue is related to the duplicate. If it isn't then please let me know so I can re-open the question. But for now, try to use `Formula2` instead of `Value`.

Comment: I cant find `Formula2`. I tried with `Value2` and `Formula` but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @JvdV: It works with `FormulaArray`. Thank you for your help, and your post.